# Webservice security

Tags: java, web-services, java-metro-framework

I have exposed one web service (Service Interface to access my application), What are the different ways to create/implement web service security?

Could anyone please suggest some idea?

Comment: What web service stack are you using? You've tagged your question with both metro and axis2, but you can't be using both.

Answer (score 1):

This http://ws.apache.org/rampart/?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using metro stack. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Using WSIT Security](https://metro.dev.java.net/guide/index.html#ahici) from the Metro Users Guide.